# How to get rid of the probability density function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A question asks: "The heights of students in a single year group in a large school can be modelled by a normal
distribution.
It is given that 40 % of the students are shorter than 1.62 m and 25 % are taller than 1.79 m .
Find the mean and standard deviation of the heights of the students."

I was able to follow the solution give until this part:
[image]

and the next step given is:
[image]
, which I don't understand how they got to. Can someone explain how they got rid of the "$P(Z < ...)$"?

I'm just starting to learn probability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a normal distribution table to find probabilities of the form $P(Z <c)$ for different values of $c$. Then, by working backwards, if you know $P(Z<c) = \alpha$, you can find $c$ given $\alpha$.

So, for $P(Z < \frac{ 1.62 - \mu}{\sigma}) = 0.4$, they found $P(Z<c) = 0.4$ is satisfied by $c=-0.2533...$. So, by comparing $P(Z < \frac{ 1.62 - \mu}{\sigma}) = 0.4$ and $P(Z<-0.2533...) = 0.4$ , we have $\frac{ 1.62 - \mu}{\sigma} = -0.2533...$.